# Training VGGish with custom dataset

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

I would like to train VGGish model with my own dataset. What should i do? If there is anyone who has done it before, Could you please share it? I am a new learner in deep learning field and I am really in need of this to complete my project.

I want to know how to train VGGish with custom dataset

```py
class VGG(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, features):
        super(VGG, self).__init__()
        self.features = features
        self.embeddings = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(512 * 4 * 6, 4096),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Linear(4096, 4096),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Linear(4096, 128),
            nn.ReLU(True))

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.features(x)

        # Transpose the output from features to
        # remain compatible with vggish embeddings
        x = torch.transpose(x, 1, 3)
        x = torch.transpose(x, 1, 2)
        x = x.contiguous()
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)

        return self.embeddings(x)


class Postprocessor(nn.Module):
    """Post-processes VGGish embeddings. Returns a torch.Tensor instead of a
    numpy array in order to preserve the gradient.

    "The initial release of AudioSet included 128-D VGGish embeddings for each
    segment of AudioSet. These released embeddings were produced by applying
    a PCA transformation (technically, a whitening transform is included as well)
    and 8-bit quantization to the raw embedding output from VGGish, in order to
    stay compatible with the YouTube-8M project which provides visual embeddings
    in the same format for a large set of YouTube videos. This class implements
    the same PCA (with whitening) and quantization transformations."
    """
```